# D3 Color Doughnut Chart issue

Tags: d3.js, interactive

I`m trying to make the rest of the chart transparent or set it to a specific color after I click on a specific slice of the doughnut. So far so good in console the filter is working if I hard-code the type it works( I set it to null at the beginning). I don't know why i can not get the slice that I click and make the rest of the chart set to that specific color. My though is that I have to update the chart somehow but with drawdata() function doesn't work ...

Here is my code:

```
    var filter = {
    device: null,
    os_version: null,
    app_version: null
};

// Creating the object Doughnut
var Doughnut = function(type) {
    // Properties
    var width = 160;
    var height = 160
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var donutWidth = 35;
    var legendRectSize = 18;
    var legendSpacing = 4;
    var type = type;

    // Array of Colors for the graph
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();
    var colorFunc = function(key) {

        var normalColor = color(key);

        if (filter[type] == null || key == filter[type]) {
            console.log("normal color")
            return normalColor;
        }
        console.log("trans color")
        return "#d5eff2";
    };

    // Graph Elements
    var chart = null;
    var svg = null;
    var path = null;
    var legend = null;



    // Our current dataSet
    var dataSet = null;

    // d3 functions
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
        .outerRadius(radius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });

    // This is the initialize method - we create the basic graph, no data
    var initialize = function(chartElement){
        chart = chartElement;
        svg = d3.select(chart)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
            ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
    };

    var update = function() {
        d3.json("./api/distribution/", function(data){
            dataSet = data;
            data.value = +data.value;
            drawData();
        });
    }

    var drawData = function() {
        path = svg.selectAll('path')
            .data(pie(dataSet[type]))
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d) {
                return colorFunc(d.data.key);
            })
            .on('click', function(d) {
                if (filter[type] == d.data.key) {
                    filter[type] = null;
                } else {
                    filter[type] = d.data.key;
                }
                console.log(filter)
               // $(chart).empty()
               drawData();
            });

          createLegends();
    };


    var createLegends = function() {
        legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
                .data(color.domain())
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'legend')
                .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
        var offset = height * color.domain().length /2;
        var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
        var vert = i * height - offset;
                    return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
                });

        legend.append('rect')
               .attr('width', legendRectSize)
               .attr('height', legendRectSize)
               .style('fill', color)
               .style('stroke', color);

        legend.append('text')
               .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
               .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               });
        };
        return{
            init: initialize,
            update: update
        }
};

    // Here we create instance of doughnuts
    var doughnutGraphs = (function() {

        var init = function() {
            // Create four doughnuts
            var doughnut1 = new Doughnut("device");
            var doughnut2 = new Doughnut("os_version");
            var doughnut3 = new Doughnut("app_version");

            // Initialize with an element
            doughnut1.init("#chart_1");
            doughnut2.init("#chart_2");
            doughnut3.init("#chart_3");

            // Update each of them with data
            doughnut1.update();
            doughnut2.update();
            doughnut3.update();
        };

        return {
            init: init
        }
        })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

Create a method to clean then call it in the drawdata()

var clean = function() {
    svg.selectAll('path').remove();

and call it .on('click')

```
 .on('click', function(d) {
                if (filter[type] == d.data.key) {
                    filter[type] = null;
                } else {
                    filter[type] = d.data.key;
                }
                console.log(filter)
               // $(chart).empty()
                clean();
                drawData();
            });
```